# Python: Printing Html in PDF using Reportlab Canvas

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

For one of my python project I am using reportlab's canvas feature to generate pdf document.

Can anyone please help me to print small subset of html (p, strong, ul, ol, li, img, alignments) on reportlab canvas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django and Reportlab Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467042/django-and-reportlab-question)

Comment: I think using platypus xpreformatted works better than the above link. Personal opinion, since I have tried both.  http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/platypus.html#module-reportlab.platypus.xpreformatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you are tying to do you should look at using Platypus with ReportLab, a built in set of classes in ReportLab for building documents out of objects representing page elements.  Or, if you want really simple, xhtml2pdf would probably be better.